# What animal's lower eye lid moves to upper one when closing eyes?

Tags: zoology, eyes, movement

I know cock's lower eye lids moves to meet the upper one when it closes its eye.  What other animals does this?  BTW, "cock-eyed" can mean upside down, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Actaully there are quite a few animals which actually moves there lower eyelids:

- Most of the birds
- Reptiles(Except Snake)
- Amphibians

Comment: Are you sure? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dgh6ABfdlAU shows a hawk's nictitating membrane moving from sidewise.

Answer (score 1):

Nictitating membrane (inner eyelid) of sharks can cover sharks eye as it moves from the upper to the lower eye lid (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nictitating_membrane).